# WordPress shortcode in text widget not passing content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an enclosing widget which works fine in post/page but when in a text widget it's not passing the content between the shortcode tags.

The shortcode looks like:

`[wpbutton]wpbutton[/wpbutton]`

and the code is:

```
add_shortcode('wpbutton', array($this, 'shortcode'));
add_filter('widget_text', array($this, 'shortcode'));

function shortcode($args, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'action' => '',
        'classes' => 'wpbutton',
    ), $args));

    echo wpbutton($action, $content, $classes);

    // Added for testing - echos in sidebar!
    if (!$content) {
        echo 'no content';
    }

}

function wpbutton($action, $content, $classes) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

In post/page content it echos whatever is between the tags but in a text widget it echos "no content"

Anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your filter function to this:

```
add_filter('widget_text', array($this, 'do_shortcode'));
```

instead of

```
add_filter('widget_text', array($this, 'shortcode'));
```

It passes the content of the text widget to the [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function of Wordpress, instead of your function. The Wordpress function will handle the shortcodes by itself and call your `shortcode` function automatically.

As seen [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-in-text-widget-1) and [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-shortcodes-work-in-a-widget).

Comment: Pretty much. The `array($this, 'function')` format is used when inside an object (I took the code out of OO content for this question) so answer is to use `add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');`. Thanks!